# What does (x>>1)&1 result?

Tags: c++, binary

I'm working with bits and I don't understand this operator.

```
unsigned int number = 6;
number = (number>>1)&1;
```

The resulting value in number is 1 and I don't know why.
6 is 0110 in binary.
If I shift 1 position to the right the result is 0011, which is 3.
The value in *number* now is 1, which is the last bit in 0011. Does the operation return the last digit??

Thanks

Comment: After the shift, the bitwise and [operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) `&` is used. So you figured out that the result is `0011` and now do a bitwise and with `1`. You will get `1`. So yes this will return the last digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you do a [right shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Right_shift_%3E%3E) operation. It shifts each bit in its left operand to the right. The number following the operator decides the number of places the bits are shifted.

```sh
0110 >> 1 = 0011
```

Then you perform a [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_&) operation, which does a logical AND of the bits in each position of a number in its binary form.

```sh
  0011
& 0001
  ----
= 0001
```

So yes, if you perform a bitwise AND operation with `1`, the result is going to be the last digit of the left operand.

Answer (score 2):

ANDing 0011 and 0001, the result is 0001. I couldn't understand what you meant to ask.